# HTML CDATA issue

Tags: java, html, xml, cdata

I'm working in Java and I have this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/uAQ94/1/

But when I want to display the final HTML, I can't see the special characters surrounded by CDATA tags.
For example:

```
<![CDATA[à]]  not show the à character
```

I need to understand this because I have to execute this code:

```
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(escapedStr));
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
        renderer.layout();
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        renderer.createPDF(os);
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

to get a pdf page.

Why CDATA doesn't show me any special characters?

Comment: Why are you using a CDATA section there in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, CDATA sections can only appear inside [foreign XML elements](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#foreign-elements), and then only on relatively modern browsers.

[Section 12.1.5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-cdata) says

> CDATA sections can only be used in foreign content (MathML or SVG).

CDATA sections are also problematic because there's no easy way to render CDATA sections whose value contains the string `"]]>"`.

For both these reasons, most HTML renderers will convert CDATA sections to regular entity escaped text nodes.

---

```
<p>
  <![CDATA[à]]>
  <![CDATA[ò]]>
  <![CDATA[è]]>+
  <![CDATA[ì]]>
</p>
```

These CDATA sections are not in foreign XML.  They are inside a regular HTML `<p>` element, so disallowed.

The simplest way to dodge encoding issues with these accented vowels is to use HTML numeric character references:

```
<p> &#224; &#242; &#232;+ &#236; </p>
```

should be equivalent (post-normalization) to your original.

Comment: The best way to specify accented vowels is to use a character encoding that supports them … which you have to do whether or not they appear in a CDATA section. Using numeric character references just makes the source code really hard to read.

Comment: @Quentin, I agree re readability, but sometimes you don't have control over the content-type headers that the HTML is served with.  For example, when generating snippets of HTML that can only appear in a body (no `<meta>`) or as part of an HTML escaper.  In that case, producing 7-bit-Latin output can be the best interop-wise.  I assume that the reason the OP is trying tricks like CDATA sections is because they have some kind of encoding interop problem.

Comment: I agree with @Quentin, use the proper encoding (probably UTF-8), and you don't have to worry about special chars, see [setXMLEncoding](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Document.html#setXMLEncoding(java.lang.String))

Comment: @lolotron, as I mentioned in my response to Quentin, that only works when you know or have control over the encoding used.  Code that does not (often library code) has to make worst case assumptions.

Comment: hey @MikeSamuel I am an expert in this topic about HTML5 but what do you mean when you said forgein element?  may MathMlL ? or something similar?  could you tell me for understand better you.